# NSNumber property of NSManagedObject with NSPredicate

Tags: ios, objective-c, nspredicate, nsmanagedobject

Here I have attribute `(name :- universal_Id)` in core data as NSNumber in modal class

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"universal_Id == %d",0];

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"universal_Id == %d",[NSNumber numberWithInt:0]];

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"universal_Id == %@",[NSNumber numberWithInt:0]];
```

Please provide me some correct solution for above predicates. Which one is the correct way to fetch data on the bases of `universal_Id`?

Answer (score 0):

`NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"universal_Id == %d",0];` 
is correct because Core Data is ORM and uses objects to represent scalar values. So when you need to store data in core data , you need to use objects. In predicate building, here you need not to use objects, scalar value is enough to build a predicate, because at the end, core data query matches the universal_Id value, not the object.

**Update**

you can also use

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.universal_Id == %d",0];
```

Comment: Hi Sandeep, then why we can't use below predicate?

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"universal_Id == %d",[NSNumber numberWithInt:0]];

Comment: @mitultrivedi here you are using format specifier for scalar type and giving parameter of object type, you can use this also, but to avoid having warnings, you should use integer type. If you want to use Object as parameter, you can use but on the other hand, you need to change %d to %@.

Comment: So final syntex will be like 

 NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"universal_Id == %d",[NSNumber numberWithInteger:0]];
OR
 NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"universal_Id == %@",[NSNumber numberWithInteger:0]];

Comment: NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"universal_Id == %d",[NSNumber numberWithInteger:0]];  with this line [NSNumber numberWithInteger:0] will be unboxed automatically. 

Second line 
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"universal_Id == %@",[NSNumber numberWithInteger:0]];  need not to unbox it. use second one.